# How to set a project wide configuration for iterations in property tests in kotest?

Tags: property-based-testing, kotest

I'd like to limit the default number of iterations for Property Based Tests in Kotest, preferably in the code (instead of using the also existing system property `kotest.proptest.default.iteration.count` inside my gradle/maven project).

The [Global Configuration | Kotest Property Testing](https://kotest.io/docs/proptest/property-test-global-config.html) page states that I can achieve this by setting `PropertyTesting.defaultIterationCount` to some value. What I don't get is where to place this assignment. The documentation for [Project Wide Configuration in the Framework](https://kotest.io/docs/framework/project-config.html) says I have to override `AbstractProjectConfig`, which sadly does not include any properties regarding PBT.

The following code works by invoking the assignemnt as a side effect:

```kotlin
import io.kotest.core.config.AbstractProjectConfig
import io.kotest.property.PropertyTesting

class TestConfig : AbstractProjectConfig() {
  init {
    PropertyTesting.defaultIterationCount = 123
  }
}
```

is there a better way configuring PBT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The global configuration for Property Testing in Kotest is not tied to Kotest framework itself, because you can use the prop testing modules from JUnit or anything.

So the way to make this work is to set `PropertyTesting.defaultIterationCount` in some kind of "before project" listener. Now if you're using Kotest framework, it's easy and you're almost there. Just put the assignment inside a beforeProject listener, and it'll be guaranteed to run before any tests.

```
class TestConfig : AbstractProjectConfig() {
   override suspend fun beforeProject() {
      PropertyTesting.defaultIterationCount = 123
   }
}
```